# Umlaut characters are not displayed properly in my JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, character-encoding

I have a jsp which has the option for uploading a file. In my case I have uploaded a file that has the name in combination of English and umlaut characters - that will be displayed in next jsp where it displays properly for example *`üß_file.xls`* when the same code display as *`?_file.xls`* in the higher environment ie.,test environment I had tried three options:

1. encoded to `UTF-8` in the encoding option as the first line in my jsp.
2. I have changed the `html:form` attribute (accept character set) to `UTF-8`.
3. I have included only SetCharacter Encoded Sevlet filter which is setting response content type to `UTF-8` and request .set character Encoding to `UTF-8`. It includes the change in  *`web.xml`* with the param to force the jsp patterns to `UTF-8` Encoding type.

Please suggest me some solutions to solve this issue in test environment (where it works fine in DEV and local environments).

Comment: Is it about `ulmaut` or the German `umlaut` (ä, ö, ü)?

Comment: @home: technically, the German umlaut ([diaeresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))) is the double point diacritical mark on top of vowel characters. the ß ([s sharp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)) doesn't fall in the same category btw.

Comment: Coming back to the concrete problem, where are those filenames stored? Are they displayed directly from disk file system? Or are they stored in the DB?

Comment: @BalusC: I know, just wanted to clarify if 'ulmaut' is a typo as I am not aware of that...

Comment: We see you made a lot of efforts making sure your page is encoded in UTF8. Have you checked if it is actually encoded properly, using firebug for example? You would go to the NET tab, were you would see your POST request, and check the response headers.

Comment: If it works in DEV and on your desktop, but not in TEST and PROD, you should discuss with your infrastructure team. Environments should not differ in cases like that.

Comment: I suppose it is stored on disk somehow. Check your File System configuration.

Comment: @Alban: the OP is seeing a question mark. This is a problem purely in the server side, not in server-client interaction, nor in the client side. If it were a problem in the client side (related to content type header, indeed), the OP wouldn't have received a legit question mark character from the server, but the received bytes would be wrongly interpreted and shown as mojibake, something like `Ã¼Ã_file.xls` when ISO-8859-1 is incorrectly been used somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the encoding of the servlet-container? E.g Tomcat might use the plattform (OS) encoding which might not be UTF-8.